# Unable to start Django app with Cloud Foundry push

Tags: python, django, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I am used to pushing Spring apps to Cloud Foundry. This is the first time I am pushing a Django app. After uploading is complete, it shows:

```
> Waiting for app to start...
Start unsuccessful
```

My app project structure is below:

```
.gitignore
Procfile
README.md
/app
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
/assets
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    data_generator.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    /migrations
        __init__.py
/tokentype
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    /migrations
        __init__.py
db.sqlite3
log_storage.log
manage.py
manifest.yml
/repo
    assetmanagement-3.9-py3-none-any.whl
    mindsphere_core-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
sdk_util.py
```

- My `runtime.txt` contains `python-3.5.x`.
- My `Procfile` contains `web: python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver`.
- My `requirements.txt` has all necessary requirements including Django and djangorestframework.
- And `manifest.yaml` has below content:

  ```
  applications:
  - name: pythondemoapp
    instances: 1
    randon-route : true
    path: .
    memory: 1GB
    env:
      HOST_ENVIRONMENT: eu1-int
  ```

When I run `cf logs pythondemoapp --recent` after the app fails to start, I get the below log, where it complains about a couple of issues:

- `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' (but I have this in my requirements.txt)`
- `Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused.` (I am not able to understand why it's Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ i.e at localhost)
- `AttributeError: module 'pip._internal' has no attribute 'utils'`

Please review the logs:

```
       2019-02-25T21:14:52.28+0530 [API/1] OUT Updated app with guid 364c5cd1-63a3-43a2-b854-23ddd751099f ({"buildpack"=>"", "disk_quota"=>512, "environment_json"=>"[PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]", "health_check_http_endpoint"=>"", "health_check_type"=>"port", "instances"=>1, "memory"=>1024, "name"=>"pythondemoapp", "space_guid"=>"3e84ef99-bf0a-4d76-897f-ddc5948a7ca1"})
       2019-02-25T21:14:53.24+0530 [API/1] OUT Uploading bits for app with guid 364c5cd1-63a3-43a2-b854-23ddd751099f
       2019-02-25T21:15:02.99+0530 [API/1] OUT Updated app with guid 364c5cd1-63a3-43a2-b854-23ddd751099f ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
       2019-02-25T21:15:03.41+0530 [API/0] OUT Creating build for app with guid 364c5cd1-63a3-43a2-b854-23ddd751099f
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.07+0530 [API/0] OUT Updated app with guid 364c5cd1-63a3-43a2-b854-23ddd751099f ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.09+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading stratos...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.09+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading nodejs_buildpack_deprecated...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.09+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading ruby_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.09+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading python_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.09+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading php_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.12+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded ruby_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.12+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading staticfile_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.12+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded stratos
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.12+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading mendix_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.13+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded python_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.13+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading go_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.13+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded php_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.14+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading dotnet_core_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.15+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded mendix_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.15+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading nodejs_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.15+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded staticfile_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.15+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading java_buildpack...
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.16+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded go_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.18+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded dotnet_core_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:04.19+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded java_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:05.18+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded nodejs_buildpack
       2019-02-25T21:15:05.18+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded nodejs_buildpack_deprecated
       2019-02-25T21:15:05.19+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell fefe8742-9a99-4e6c-b773-034414c67b95 creating container for instance b1aaa9db-288e-4a97-b7ae-38b71b82f150
       2019-02-25T21:15:08.00+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell fefe8742-9a99-4e6c-b773-034414c67b95 successfully created container for instance b1aaa9db-288e-4a97-b7ae-38b71b82f150
       2019-02-25T21:15:08.33+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading app package...
       2019-02-25T21:15:08.33+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloading build artifacts cache...
       2019-02-25T21:15:08.40+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded app package (177.4K)
       2019-02-25T21:15:14.84+0530 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded build artifacts cache (116.2M)
       2019-02-25T21:15:16.23+0530 [STG/0] OUT -----> Python Buildpack version 1.6.28
       2019-02-25T21:15:16.23+0530 [STG/0] OUT -----> Supplying Python
       2019-02-25T21:15:16.23+0530 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing python 3.5.6
       2019-02-25T21:15:16.23+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Copy [/tmp/cache/final/dependencies/ef600f00661a7602f82a830e3ad44c62ea50a77f92c1125bd0ce5b53381ee337/python-3.5.6-linux-x64-cflinuxfs2-e0bd0cbf.tgz]
       2019-02-25T21:15:18.62+0530 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing pip-pop 0.1.3
       2019-02-25T21:15:18.62+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Copy [/tmp/cache/final/dependencies/5b0bd37a974d85d0614bb4c03eb3f8fb800c9e6c04e0a17046c18387f04e0b89/pip-pop-0.1.3-fc106ef6.tar.gz]
       2019-02-25T21:15:22.27+0530 [STG/0] OUT -----> Running Pip Install
       2019-02-25T21:15:22.73+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Processing ./repo/mindsphere_core-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:22.75+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Processing ./repo/assetmanagement-3.9-py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:22.79+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting PyJWT==1.7.1 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
       2019-02-25T21:15:22.86+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/8b/6a9f14b5f781697e51259d81657e6048fd31a113229cf346880bb7545565/PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:22.87+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.0 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
       2019-02-25T21:15:22.90+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:22.92+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting pytz==2018.9 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 5))
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.08+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.20+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting requests==2.21.0 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 6))
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.28+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/e3/20f3d364d6c8e5d2353c72a67778eb189176f08e873c9900e10c0287b84b/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.30+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting six==1.12.0 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 7))
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.32+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.32+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting urllib3==1.24.1 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 8))
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.36+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/00/ee1d7de624db8ba7090d1226aebefab96a2c71cd5cfa7629d6ad3f61b79e/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.38+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting certifi==2018.11.29 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 9))
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.41+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/e0/accfc1b56b57e9750eba272e24c4dddeac86852c2bebd1236674d7887e8a/certifi-2018.11.29-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.41+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting chardet==3.0.4 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 10))
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.43+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.44+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting Django==2.1.7 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 11))
       2019-02-25T21:15:23.67+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/87/fbd666c4f87591ae25b7bb374298e8629816e87193c4099d3608ef11fab9/Django-2.1.7-py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:24.52+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting djangorestframework==3.9.1 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 12))
       2019-02-25T21:15:24.60+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/13/0f394111124e0242bf3052c5578974e88e62e3715f0daf76b7c987fc6705/djangorestframework-3.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:24.67+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting idna==2.8 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 13))
       2019-02-25T21:15:24.69+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:24.70+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Collecting pip==19.0.3 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 14))
       2019-02-25T21:15:24.77+0530 [STG/0] OUT          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       2019-02-25T21:15:24.87+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Installing collected packages: PyJWT, six, chardet, idna, urllib3, certifi, requests, mindsphere-core, python-dateutil, assetmanagement, pytz, Django, djangorestframework, pip
       2019-02-25T21:15:29.44+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Successfully installed Django-2.1.7 PyJWT-1.7.1 assetmanagement-3.9 certifi-2018.11.29 chardet-3.0.4 djangorestframework-3.9.1 idna-2.8 mindsphere-core-0.1.0 pip-19.0.3 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2018.9 requests-2.21.0 six-1.12.0 urllib3-1.24.1
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR Traceback (most recent call last):
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR   File "/tmp/contents555080451/deps/0/bin/pip-grep", line 77, in <module>
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR     main()
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR   File "/tmp/contents555080451/deps/0/bin/pip-grep", line 73, in main
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR     grep(**kwargs)
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR   File "/tmp/contents555080451/deps/0/bin/pip-grep", line 50, in grep
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR     r = Requirements(reqfile)
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR   File "/tmp/contents555080451/deps/0/bin/pip-grep", line 30, in __init__
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR     self.load(reqfile)
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR   File "/tmp/contents555080451/deps/0/bin/pip-grep", line 39, in load
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR     finder = PackageFinder([], [], session=requests)
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR   File "/tmp/contents555080451/deps/0/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 339, in __init__
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR     impl=implementation,
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR   File "/tmp/contents555080451/deps/0/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/pep425tags.py", line 340, in get_supported
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR     if is_manylinux2010_compatible():
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR   File "/tmp/contents555080451/deps/0/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/pep425tags.py", line 196, in is_manylinux2010_compatible
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR     return pip._internal.utils.glibc.have_compatible_glibc(2, 12)
       2019-02-25T21:15:30.39+0530 [STG/0] ERR AttributeError: module 'pip._internal' has no attribute 'utils'
       2019-02-25T21:15:49.36+0530 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 0
       2019-02-25T21:15:49.36+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
       2019-02-25T21:15:49.36+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet...
       2019-02-25T21:15:49.36+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...
       2019-02-25T21:15:50.50+0530 [API/2] OUT Creating droplet for app with guid 364c5cd1-63a3-43a2-b854-23ddd751099f
       2019-02-25T21:15:51.64+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (116.2M)
       2019-02-25T21:15:57.71+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded droplet (55.1M)
       2019-02-25T21:15:57.72+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading complete
       2019-02-25T21:15:58.10+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell fefe8742-9a99-4e6c-b773-034414c67b95 stopping instance b1aaa9db-288e-4a97-b7ae-38b71b82f150
       2019-02-25T21:15:58.10+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell fefe8742-9a99-4e6c-b773-034414c67b95 destroying container for instance b1aaa9db-288e-4a97-b7ae-38b71b82f150
       2019-02-25T21:15:58.42+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4a93eb5-83ac-46c9-b793-6f307874727d creating container for instance ea5664c5-6e4c-47b9-737d-35e7
       2019-02-25T21:15:59.80+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4a93eb5-83ac-46c9-b793-6f307874727d successfully created container for instance ea5664c5-6e4c-47b9-737d-35e7
       2019-02-25T21:16:00.42+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell fefe8742-9a99-4e6c-b773-034414c67b95 successfully destroyed container for instance b1aaa9db-288e-4a97-b7ae-38b71b82f150
       2019-02-25T21:16:03.50+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
       2019-02-25T21:16:04.43+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Operations to perform:
       2019-02-25T21:16:04.43+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
       2019-02-25T21:16:04.44+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Running migrations:
       2019-02-25T21:16:04.44+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   No migrations to apply.
       2019-02-25T21:16:05.14+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Performing system checks...
       2019-02-25T21:16:05.38+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
       2019-02-25T21:16:05.40+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT February 25, 2019 - 15:46:05
       2019-02-25T21:16:05.40+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Django version 2.1.7, using settings 'app.settings'
       2019-02-25T21:16:05.40+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
       2019-02-25T21:16:05.40+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
       2019-02-25T21:17:03.84+0530 [CELL/0] ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
       2019-02-25T21:17:03.84+0530 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.
       2019-02-25T21:17:15.03+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4a93eb5-83ac-46c9-b793-6f307874727d stopping instance ea5664c5-6e4c-47b9-737d-35e7
       2019-02-25T21:17:15.03+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4a93eb5-83ac-46c9-b793-6f307874727d destroying container for instance ea5664c5-6e4c-47b9-737d-35e7
```

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but you should absolutely not be using `runserver` in production.

Comment: A Word document is even worse than an offsite link to text...

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you please give me some link for better alternative. I have tried with waitress and gunicorn, but those were not working for me

Comment: It seems like the fundamental problem is that your app doesn't listen on the right port - it needs to use the `PORT` env var

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you share some links how to do that. I am new to django and python

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the edit

Comment: Did you try googling `django runserver set port`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have changed the proc file content to "web: python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver $PORT" , but still same issue

Comment: Gunicorn *is* the better alternative. If you couldn't get it working, you should probably be asking a question about that instead.

Comment: +1 for gunicorn. I use it when deploying my Django app to CF, and it works great. This [tutorial](https://www.ianhuston.net/2017/10/bringing-django-to-cloud-foundry/) might help.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Previously i was trying to run gunicorn command on my windows local. Now I realized this is meant for unix only. Thanks, my issue is solved, however I am getting new issue now :)

Comment: @asherbar Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding the solution for the future visitors.
My app was using the development server (WSGI) which comes along with django. So when my start command "python manage.py runserver" was running, it was trying to start the app at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

So I have added a production ready server "gunicorn" and changed my start command in procfile to

```
web: python manage.py migrate && gunicorn app.wsgi --log-file -
```

After this the app successfully started in cloud foundry.